# Making a YUI3 treeble

Tags: javascript, yui, yui-datatable

I have been looking at YUI3 for about a week or two and am very much impressed by it. I came across the [this](http://jafl.github.com/yui3-gallery/treeble/) example for making a tree table in YUI 3 (called treeble). I also had a look at YUI 2 and it seems that many of the utilities present in YUI2 have still not propagated to YUI 3, particularly for the DataTable. Is there a way to make the YUI 3 table mutable something like [this](http://satyam.com.ar/yui/2.6.0/rowedit.html).

Now I am confused whether to build my app with YUI3 or YUI 2. YUI 3 seems to be more readable and easier to understand but if I use YUI3 I might loose out to some utilities available in YUI 2.

I also came across [a method](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/examples/yui/yui-compat.html) to use YUI 2 objects in YUI 3.

Any suggestions.